# dpkg dependencies for a custom Ubuntu CD

Tags: dpkg, dependencies

Recently I have been working on some projects where I need to add extra packages to default Ubuntu install CDs.

I have managed to add these packages successfully and make their icons show up on the unity sidebar after the user finishes installing off the CD.

However, when adding these new packages, I have found that sorting out their dependencies has been painful.  If a new package has dependencies A, B, C and D, and everything except D is included on the on-CD repositories, the installer wizard will error-out unless D is included on the CD, even if the internet is connected (please correct me if my analogy is wrong).

In this case, adding D is easy.  But sometimes debian packages have dozens upon dozens of dependencies, and figuring out whether they are included on the CD by hand is cumbersome and time consuming.  Sometimes I accidentally miss a dependency and only find out later when the installer CD errors out.

I'm thinking there has to be an easier way to do this.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-cache depends --recurse <pkg>` will show all dependencies (with dependencies of dependencies, dependencies of dependencies of dependencies, etc). Then you may download them all and put to your CD.

Comment: Hi strangeman.  Thanks very much for your help.  apt-get depends --recurse is exactly what I want, except that it includes suggestions too.  In other words, it lists dependencies of dependencies of suggestions (and dependencies of suggestions of suggestions, etc).  In total I got 8000 packages to install for a dpkg with only 4 package dependencies in its control file.  A little bit too much.  Is there some way to get a recursive list with just the bare minimum? -Andrew

Comment: Of course. Try use `apt-cache depends --recurse -i <pkg>` The '-i' key print only important dependencies. Causes only Depends and Pre-Depends relations to be printed.

Comment: Thanks! Using '-i' I have reduced the list to just 91 entries.  From these 91 entries, only 7 are not included on-CD. :).

Answer (score 0):

[uck](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/uck) [image: Install uck]Use uck to add extra packages in the live cd . It will add dependencies automatically